# How to compile golang program with .a file (without source)

Tags: go, package

I need to compile my program - main.go with package bigPak without source. Exist only bigPak.a tnto GOPATH/pkg.

Can you give me example of compile main.go with bigPak.a ?

Comment: It **might** be possible, but if it is you'd have to manually invoke the linker and compiler, it would be pretty hard to work with.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406122/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's dead simple: Just produce a fake bigPak package in the right $GOPATH/src location (an empty `package bigPak` will do) and (**important**!!) make sure this synthetic source has a modification time **before** the modification time of bigPak.a. The go tool should just work like this.

Go is designed to be able to compile from the .a files without transitively reading their includes. The Go tool uses the source (only) to check if an .a files needs to be recompiled (because the source is newer.

Comment: I tried it locally and it did work. Make sure the .a stems from the right compiler version and the paths are ok. (And: showing error messages and detailed setup would make debugging easier.)

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you... I have bigPak.a what should I do so that my program main.go compile? Please give me an example that would be great!

Comment: Assuming bigPak.a is the object file of package some/big/code and your main program does `import "some/big/code"` and is located in $GOPATH/src/me/myprog. You are on 64bit linux and bigPak.a has been compiled for this platform by the Go compiler (not C code!) and declares itself as `package sbc`. tbc...

Comment: ... Put bigPak.a in $GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64/some/big/code. Do `mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/some/big/code; echo "package sbc" > $GOPATH/src/some/big/code/sbc.go; touch -t 199901011200 $GOPATH/src/some/big/code/sbc.go`. In $GOPATH/src/me/myprog run `go build`, maybe with the -v or -x flag.

Comment: OK... 1) I created package GOPATH/src/book/bigPak/bigPak.go with method GetData() string 2) install it (put it into GOPATH/pkg/... 3) remove GOPATH/src/book and create it new without GetData, only package bigPak; 4) add import book/bigPak into GOPATH/src/comeprogram/main.go and try to build it - faild!!! If I add empty method into bigPak.go that build succes but GetData now empty becouse compile from source

Comment: You forgot to `touch` the fake source. What you did makes the go tool think it has to recompile src/book/bigPak/bigPak.go which it does and then getData is missing.

Comment: Thack you! And is there a simpler way to exchange packets (.a files) without source code?

Comment: Well: two files (the real .a and a fake .go) with the single constraints of one timestamp before the other is already pretty simple... A zip/tar/whatever file containing both ready to be unpacked: How could that be made any simpler?

Comment: @user2614682, no [there's no simpler way yet](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2775).