# Using binary packages directly

Tags: go

I'm writing a library in Go. I'm planning to distribute it, and with a main requirement of '**without source codes**'.

For testing, I have created two workspaces like following,

**WS1**

- bin/
- pkg/linux_amd64/lib.a
- src/lib/src.go

**WS2**

- bin/
- pkg/
- src/main/main.go

My first workspace (WS1) is the actual dummy library, which has some utility functions. Second workspace (WS2) has main function which uses the package (lib.a) from WS1.

Everything was working good until I remove the sources from WS1. If I remove the directory /lib/src.go in WS1, I'm getting the following error during go build,

> main.go:5:2: cannot find package "lib" in any of:
>   /usr/local/go/src/pkg/lib (from $GOROOT)   ../Testing/ws1/src/lib
>   (from $GOPATH)

The above message indicates us that we should keep the source files as well. **Precompiled binary packages alone cannot be used directly**.

Based on few suggestions online, we may keep some dummy sources with timestamp value lesser than binary packages' timestamp. But, this doesn't seems to be a feasible solution for us. What happens if timestamp of the dummy sources got updated unfortunately?

I have seen similar issue discussed here,
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2775

**My Questions:**

1. Distributing the sources is the only possibility in Golang?
2. Why Go is not providing a provision for using '.a' files directly?
3. If keeping the source is mandatory for Go, why this small thing is
   not mentioned anywhere in Go? (or) Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Go compiler just needs the `.a` files. If you ship them anybody will be able to use your package without the source code.

**BUT** your users will have to invoke the compiler (e.g. `6g`, not the `go` tool) manually. If you ship a `myfoo.a` file *and* a dummy source `myfoo.go` containing just `package myfoo` and the timestamp of `myfoo.a` is newer than that of `myfoo.go` (and you put everything in place) you may use the `go` tool.

**Update**: Newer version of the go tool detect deleted files and require all files (possibly empty) with the proper filenames and older timestamps in the src folder.
Managing a timestamp should not be a dealbreaker.

Don't get fooled that the `go` tool *is* Go: It is a dead convenient tool to build, test, get, whatever your Go code, but it is neither the language nor the compiler nor the linker.

BTW: There is really no point in not distributing the sources.

Comment: Thanks Volker! Now understand the problem here. Reason I was pressing on the 'go build' is most of the developers will anyways uses this tool for their projects.

Comment: Heads up: this trick doesn't work anymore as of Go 1.5, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12186).

Answer (score 6):

The binary-only packages will be available in go1.7 (August 2016) - https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.7

> This release adds experimental, minimal support for building programs using binary-only packages, packages distributed in binary form without the corresponding source code. This feature is needed in some commercial settings but is not intended to be fully integrated into the rest of the toolchain. For example, tools that assume access to complete source code will not work with such packages, and there are no plans to support such packages in the “go get” command.

The proposal is at https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/2775-binary-only-packages.md , https://tip.golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages has more information about the new feature.

Comment: Support was dropped.

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: @425nesp https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages

Comment: binary-only-packages need go versions `1.7 ~ 1.12`.  
https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#binary-only

Answer (score 5):

The binary-only packages is supported in go 1.7 now.

You can only provide .a files and fake go files without source code to distribute it now.

Here is a [detailed example and a script of Go1.7 binary package generator.](https://github.com/YongHaoWu/golang-binary-package-generator)

myframework/frameImplement.go

```
package myframework

import "fmt"

func Hello(name string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s!", name)
}
```

main/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang-binary-package-generator/myframework"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(" start program ")
    fmt.Println(" print program :", myframework.Hello("print something now"))
}
```

If I want to hide my framework's source code, just build it with `go build -i -o $GOPATH/pkg/framework.a`, then modify your source code to

```
//go:binary-only-package

package framework

//you can add function prototype here for go doc etc, but no necessary.
```

, which you can use my binary package generator(script) to help you.

Comment: please post example answer here, then references

Comment: any tool to auto add function prototype? a large amount functions in my project.

Comment: go versions requirement: `1.7 ~ 1.12`.  
Go 1.12 is the last release that will support binary-only packages.

Answer (score 2):

The decision to drop the feature:

[cmd/go: drop support for binary-only packages](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152)