# How to use/distribute a binary package without Go source code

Tags: go

Basically my folder structure is as below:

```
bin/               
pkg/
    linux_amd64/         
        github.com/user/
            stringutil.a  
src/
    github.com/user/
        hello/
            hello.go   (main file)  
        stringutil/
            stringutil.go
```

`hello.go` is the main program that imports some function from `stringutil.go`.

After running `go install`, `stringutil.a` is created under `pkg` (as above).

My question is, can I run `go install` again without `stringutil.go` source since I already have `stringutil.a`?

I'm a Java programmer and new to Go. Usually in Java, during compilation, we can import the compiled jar file to the classpath and do compilation.

How can I do the same thing in Go? If I have a compiled package, `stringutil.a`, how can I distribute this file to someone and let them use it without exposing the original source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using binary packages directly - Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406122/using-binary-packages-directly-golang)

Answer (score 4):

You put your compiled package into the wrong folder.

The `pkg` folder of your Go workspace contains compiled package objects organized into subfolders based on the target architecture they are compiled to, for example `linux_amd64` or `windows_amd64`. Inside that the path of the parent package follows, and the direct parent folder is the place to put the compiled package object into.

Check where `go install` puts your package object, and mirror that folder structure.

So for example if your package is `path/to/parent/package/abc` and you compile to linux 64-bit, you should put its compiled package file into a folder like:

```
myworkspace/pkg/linux_amd64/path/to/parent/package/abc.a
```

or in case of Windows 64-bit:

```
myworkspace/pkg/windows_amd64/path/to/parent/package/abc.a
```

This page gives you more details: [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

**Notes:**

By doing this you will limit the possible targets to compile your app to, as a compiled package object is only for a specific platform. The preferred way to distribute your packages in Go is in source code form.