# Is possible in Go to create something like static or dynamic library and remove source from both projects and put on one neutral place?

Tags: go

I have couple files with same code, one package for example `mailer`, `shared between two projects` in Go. In both projects I have copied exactly the same code and it works.
Is possible in Go to create something like static or dynamic library, like in c or c++, and remove source from both projects and put on one neutral place ?
How to achieve this in Go ?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523664/how-to-compile-golang-program-with-a-file-without-source

Comment: Theoretically you only need 1 workspace, even for multiple go projects. This one workspace can hold the source of multiple projects and required external libraries. Do this and you won't have to duplicate your external source files. Distributing and using compiled packages is discouraged in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package for each function (like mailer) and place them in a different GOPATH of common libraries.

In each project add this path to the `GOPATH` (`PROJECT_PATH:COMMON_PATH`).

Alternatively, if you can share the code, save the package in Github (package src only, without folder struct) and use `go get` to fetch the package and keep it updated.